# Magento 2 - Turn off Cart & Checkout off for 1 website

Tags: magento2, checkout, websites, multidomain

I have a 1 Magento instance running 3 websites. Is it possible to turn off the cart and checkout functionality only for 1 website

Answer (score 0):

[Not test yet] We have a config for enabling/disabling onepage checkout already: **STORES > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Enable Onepage Checkout**. But, there is no config for turning on/off the cart. We need to build our custom logic.